# Append int onto string within for loop : Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to append an incremental value onto the end of a string, but the format isn't right, as its printing below it, rather than onto the end. It should be:
**password1900
password1901
password1902**

But its printing as:

password

1900

password

1901

password

1902

Here's what's I've got so far:

```
fh = open('Password.txt')
OutPut = open("OutPut.txt", 'w')
i = 1900
for line in fh:
    line+=str(i)
    print(line)
    i += 1
fh.close()
OutPut.close()
```

Comment: `line ` has newline character.... use `line = line.strip() + str(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
print(line, end=' ')
```

because in end of print() it takes new line character '\n' every time after successfully execution.
end is default argument in print function which specify which character do you want to keep in end in print()...

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.